# Fluent date_range mapping without defining Nest.DateRange property on POCO

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am attempting to use fluent mapping to map to a date_range field with the Nest client for elasticsearch.  I understand how to do so when I define the Nest.DateRange as a property on my POCO, as done below.

POCO with Nest.DateRange

```cs
    public class MyEvent
    {
        public Nest.DateRange MyDateRange { get; set; }   
    }
```

Associated Mapping

```cs
             .Map<MyEvent>(map => map
                 .AutoMap()
                 .Properties(properties => properties
                     .DateRange(dateRange => dateRange
                         .Name(name => name.MyDateRange)
                     )
                 )
             )
```

However, I would achieve the same thing without the dependency on Nest.DateRange as part of my POCO

Instead, I wish to create the date_range mapping from two standard DateTime properties

```cs
    public class MyEvent
    {
        public DateTime? StartUTC { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndUTC { get; set; }
    }
```

Is this achievable with the high level client?

Note: Ideally I would like to map from nullable `DateTime?` properties, however, that is not critical. If it can only be done with the non-nullable `DateTime`, that is sufficient

Comment: My question would be why would you _not_ want to take a dependency on `Nest.DateRange` on a POCO that maps to JSON documents within Elasticsearch?

Comment: I use the same POCO as both the model of my primary data store with the MongoDb c# driver as well as the model for the Nest index.  I'm trying to avoid including a type specific to elastic on the POCO that feeds both data stores,  while gaining the ability to use the powerful elastic date_range intersect search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DateRange type](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/6.x/src/Nest/CommonOptions/Range/Ranges.cs#L6-L19) in 6.x is

```cs
public class DateRange
{
    [JsonProperty("gt")]
    public DateTimeOffset? GreaterThan { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gte")]
    public DateTimeOffset? GreaterThanOrEqualTo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lt")]
    public DateTimeOffset? LessThan { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lte")]
    public DateTimeOffset? LessThanOrEqualTo { get; set; }
}
```

so to create your own type to do the same, you can use `PropertNameAttribute` (which still requires the dependency on NEST), or use `DataMemberAttribute` from System.Runtime.Serialization

```cs
public class MyDateRange
{
    [DataMember(Name = "gt")]
    public DateTimeOffset? GreaterThan { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "gte")]
    public DateTimeOffset? GreaterThanOrEqualTo { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "lt")]
    public DateTimeOffset? LessThan { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "lte")]
    public DateTimeOffset? LessThanOrEqualTo { get; set; }
}
```

and you would also need to explicitly map it

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "my_index";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<MyDocument>(mm => mm
                // automap
                .AutoMap()
                // now override any auto inferred mappings
                .Properties(p => p
                    .DateRange(dr =>dr 
                        .Name(n => n.DateRange)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    client.IndexDocument(new MyDocument
    {
       DateRange = new MyDateRange
       {
           GreaterThan = DateTime.UtcNow.Date,
           LessThan = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(1)
       }
    });
}

public class MyDocument
{
    public MyDateRange DateRange { get; set; }
}
```

In my opinion though, you may want to have separate POCOs for interaction with Elasticsearch

Comment: I appreciate the answer as well as advice.  I am going to refactor and use a separate POCO specific for Elasticsearch interaction